# Command line GDAL not returning anything

Tags: image-processing, command-line, tiff, gdal, wgs84

I am trying to get the pixel locations from their latitude and longitude coordinates in an .NTF raster DigitalGlobe image. I'm trying to use gdallocationinfo, however, when I enter it into the command line I am getting no output.

Here are the commands that return nothing:

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo -wgs84 stereo1ntf.NTF -156.7727265 71.25074096
```

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo -xml -wgs84 stereo1ntf.NTF -156.7727265 71.25074096
```

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo -l_srs wgs84 stereo1ntf.NTF -156.7727265 71.25074096
```

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo -l_srs EPSG:4326 stereo1ntf.NTF -156.7727265 71.25074096
```

Here is what commands return errors:

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo -geoloc stereo1ntf.NTF -156.7727265 71.25074096
ERROR 1: Cannot get geotransform
```

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo -wgs84 -geoloc stereo1ntf.NTF -156.7727265 71.25074096
ERROR 1: Cannot get geotransform
```

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo -l_srs 4326 stereo1ntf.NTF -156.7727265 71.25074096
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
4326
```

I tried running just the command with just pixel location, and that returned something, so I know it is reading the file, I just don't know why it's not working to give it coordinates:

```
(pygdal) D:\Snowmelt_Utqiagvik_2021\Stereo_Pairs\March_21_tasking\pipeline>gdallocationinfo stereo1ntf.NTF 0 1
Report:
  Location: (0P,1L)
  Band 1:
    Value: 612
```

Here is what gdalinfo returns about the image's coordinate system:

```
Driver: NITF/National Imagery Transmission Format
Files: stereo1ntf.NTF
Size is 43008, 43008
GCP Projection =
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Comment: hi, was there an error msg?

Comment: Your file does not have a geotransform, does it cover the whole world?

Comment: There was no error message for the first set of commands. It covers about a 13x13km area in Northern Alaska. What is a geotransform?

Comment: I looked into this a little more, my image has GCPs instead of a GeoTransform, does anyone know if it is possible to get pixel locations in this way in that case?